# Trouble with css on apple devices

Tags: html, css, ios, page-title

I have a problem with the CSS of a Title on some apple devices. I have this CSS code (for a H1 HTML title)

```
.title_principal {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff00db,#9400ff);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
color: transparent; }
```

On desktop looks like this

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG3sh.png)

The page on iPhone 12 looks like this

[Iphone12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxunW.png)

The page on iPhone 10 doesn't show the title

[Iphone10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNhvr.png)

The page on iPhone 8 doesn't show the title

[Iphone8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0QWH.png)

The page on iPad doesn't show the title either

[IPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRor4.png)

I don't have any idea why some devices show the title and some others just no. Any solutions?

Comment: What IOS versions are there on each of those devices? Have you tried adding background-clip as well as -webkit-background-clip?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that one but nothing.
iPhone 12 ios 15.4.1
Ipad Air 2 ios 14.8.1
The other ones are not mine so I dunno that info

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is in the font, I recently had problems with .ttf fonts, I had to generate the font with other extensions and then it worked correctly again

Comment: Yeah, I do something similar, just delete the h1 title and put an image. Btw the problem it's still there.